# Remote installation of exe using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script to copy a file to remote servers C:\temp and also to execute the exe file remotely. But the problem here is, it is copying .exe file to c:\temp of the remote machine, but not executing the exe.

Can anyone help me to correct here ?

```
ForEach ($Computer in Get-Content C:\scripts\servers.txt)
{
 Copy-Item -Path '\\serverA\c$\scripts\Firefox Setup 52.0.1.exe' -Destination \\$Computer\c$\temp\;
 Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { & "C:\temp\Firefox Setup 52.0.1.exe -ms" } 
}
```

Comment: Try `& "C:\temp\Firefox Setup 52.0.1.exe" -ms`

Comment: I have tried this, but doesn't run the exe

Comment: have you tried `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\temp\Firefox Setup 52.0.1.exe" -ArgumentList "-ms"`?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**,
Step by step breif explation is given for  [Installing-remote-software](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-04-22-Powershell-installing-remote-software/) using Powershell